# cloudsearch query throwing unexecpeted character error

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, boto, amazon-cloudsearch

I am making a cloud search query in my google appengine project using boto
the parameters looks like so:

```
params = {'size': 20,
          'rank': ['-score', '-is_instant'],
          't': {'ranking': '1..100'},
          'bq': u"(and city:'london')",
          }
```

This does not return the expected result, it returns all the records of city london. the range filter I am to apply to get only the top 100 ranked records is not having any affect. I do i rewrite this so that i get top 100 ranked records from london?

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of CS? I have never seen a 't' param, and I don't see it on here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/search-api.html

Comment: Also you will never get 100 results with that query when you have "'size': 20". The results are given in ranked order so if your ranking expression is correct, you can just take the first 100 results.

Comment: @alexroussos : these params are based boto search function :
http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudsearch.html#boto.cloudsearch.search.SearchConnection.search
According to this documents 't' is used to add range on certain fields. I know that this will get me only 20 results.. but it will get me first 20 of the top-100 records

Comment: Maybe try sorting by ranking instead (don't know why your query isn't working but that should accomplish the same thing if I understand correctly).